# How to refer and bind to a Velocity Email Template at runtime?

Tags: java, velocity, dotcms

I have a Java program, to call a velocity template from dotcms. I need to  know where to place the vm file and how to locate in Java. I am using this link.

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075966/core-java/start-up-the-velocity-template-engine.html

Comment: The vm file has to be placed in the classpath. I assume there is something like "java.exe -classpath... package.MainClass". Try something like this: "java.exe -classpath path_to_your_vm_file,some_other_files package.Main.Class".

Comment: Have you tried using any code to attempt just opening the file? I don't see how velocity specifically relates to the question

Comment: opening a file in java is  fine. But when it comes to velocity, the engine has to locate the file properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution.
We can place it any where inside web-inf folder.

The link was helpful :

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075966/core-java/start-up-the-velocity-template-engine.html

and path can be, path = "/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.vm";